# Ektron Pagebuilder JQuery interferes with Scripts in Edit Mode in IE8

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-8, ektron

Recently I discovered that for whatever reason on one of my sites, pagebuilder seems to be stopping my scripts from loading while its multiview is switched to the edit view. This is true both of scripts simply sitting in HTML inside of the edit view, and of scripts dynamically added via Ektron's `JS.RegisterJSInclude` method.

However, my dynamic scripts load find so long as i add

```
JS.RegisterJSInclude(this, JS.ManagedScript.EktronJS);
```

as the first include.

That was fine and well, but I recently discovered that this script fails to run in IE8, causing all of my edit scripts to fail. So, my question is: Can the script stripping behavior of pagebuilder be disabled, or is there a workaround using EktronJS to get it to run in IE8?

Ektron 8.6.1, Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Ektron has any "script stripping" functionality, more likely is that there is a Javascript error on the page which is introduced when in edit mode due to the extra Javascript files that are loaded.

The "EktronJS" file that you are registering is actually the jQuery library that is bundled with Ektron.  Ektron's own jQuery files depend upon the core jQuery library being loaded.  However it is normally added automatically - without it the client side PageBuilder functionality will not work.

Ektron v8.6 should support IE8 and higher, so you have no problems there.

I would recommend creating a very basic PageBuilder wireframe - don't use your MasterPages - you just want the bare essentials.  Add the RegisterJSInclude, then add your custom jQuery files one at a time, see if your Javascript works ok, then add the next file and keep going.

This process will likely show that there is a specific Javascript file which fails in IE8.

Comment: Well, debugging that way did find a script misbehaving in IE8...but only in edit mode, somehow. Seems to be an interaction with either that version or JQuery or Ektron's changes to it. 

That said, Ektron is most certainly doing some sort of suppression of the scripts, though. I created a second multiview on this page and it flips back and fourth running scripts in both views just fine. Very odd. I will start a new question to try to dig into that further.